# How to prove B from a premise in which B does not occur using natural deduction?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am preparing for my first logic exam and in the test examples I've come across the following question:

Prove by natural deduction:

```
B from premise A ∧ ¬A
```

I am unsure how to proceed in formulating this proof as B does not bear any relation to the premise. Does someone know how to proceed with such a proof? What can I assume about B's relation to the premise?

Comment: Use [EFQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) aka [$\bot$-elim](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the quick reply. I just looked at a short video where they do an example proof using that principle. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvrJYZb595Y) 

I tried doing something similar to that video in fitch where I assumed B to be a premise alongside the given premise with as goal B. However, even without proving anything fitch already accepts B as true (as I assumed it was.) Do you know what would be the premise for this proof?

EDIT: okay nvm I have to make a subproof for B. Thank you once again, I think I got it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof in the logic software program Fitch:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here are the questions:

> I am unsure how to proceed in formulating this proof as $B$ does not bear any relation to the premise. Does someone know how to proceed with such a proof? What can I assume about B's relation to the premise?

Since $B$ does not appear in the premises it may be that the premises are contradictory. From a contradiction anything follows (in particular, $B$). If one can show that the premises are contradictory, then one can use the rule of explosion (x) or *[ex falso quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)* to derive $B$.

This is actually the case since $A$ and $¬A$ are contradictory.  Here is a proof of $A ∧ ¬A ∴ B$ which you can enter in this [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) to verify for yourself:

[image]